# How does this transparent extension come with a plot in lineplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

The plot in documentation looks like this :
[image]
with code

```
sns.lineplot(x="timepoint", y="signal",
             hue="region", style="event",
             data=fmri)
```

and
mine comes out to be like this
[image]
for code :

```
sns.lineplot(
            # data=fmri, 
             x=df["_C_UP"]["s"][:10],
             y=df["_C_UP"]["px"][:10]
            #  hue="event"
             );
```

How do I get the same effect for those lines ( that transparent color around it )

here is what my data looks like

```
#Energy s   py  pz  px  dxy dyz dz2 dxz dx2 tot
50  -17.98094   0.72320 0.31781 0.00000 0.31882 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.35982
51  -17.87394   0.29726 0.14415 0.00000 0.14491 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.58632
52  -17.76794   0.63694 0.02456 0.00000 0.02484 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.68634
53  -17.66194   1.78595 0.06032 0.00001 0.06139 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.90766
54  -17.55494   1.97809 0.09038 0.00001 0.09192 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 2.16040
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `fmri` datasets, there are actually multiple observations for each time point and subgroup, for example, at timepoint == 14 :

```
fmri[fmri['timepoint']==14]

    subject timepoint   event   region  signal
1   s5  14  stim    parietal    -0.080883
57  s13 14  stim    parietal    -0.033713
58  s12 14  stim    parietal    -0.068297
59  s11 14  stim    parietal    -0.114469
60  s10 14  stim    parietal    -0.052288
61  s9  14  stim    parietal    -0.130267
```

So the line you see, is actually the mean of all these observations (stratified by group) and the ribbon is the 95% confidence interval of this mean. For example, you can turn this off by doing:

```
sns.lineplot(x="timepoint", y="signal",
             hue="region", style="event",
             data=fmri,ci=None)
```

[image]

So to get the exact plot, you need to have multiple observations or replicates. If you don't, and your intention is to just connect the points, you cannot get a confidence interval.

If you want to look at a trend line, one thing you can try is a polynomial smooth. And it makes sense to plot the data as points too.

Using an example from the same fmri dataset:

```
df = fmri[(fmri['subject']=="s5") & (fmri['event']== "stim") & (fmri['region'] == "frontal")]
sns.regplot(data=df,x = "timepoint",y = "signal",order=3)
```

[image]

Or use a loess smooth, which is more complicated (see [this post](https://james-brennan.github.io/posts/lowess_conf/) about what is drawn below )

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skmisc.loess import loess

lfit = loess(df['timepoint'],df['signal'])
lfit.fit()
pred = lfit.predict(df['timepoint'], stderror=True)
conf = pred.confidence()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.scatterplot(data=df,x = "timepoint",y = "signal",ax=ax)
sns.lineplot(x = df["timepoint"],y = pred.values,ax=ax,color="#A2D2FF")
ax.fill_between(df['timepoint'],conf.lower, conf.upper, alpha=0.1,color="#A2D2FF")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the data. The plot from the seaborn documentation that you show is based on a dataset where for every x value there are several y values (repeated measurements). The lines in the plot then indicate the means of those y values, and the shaded regions indicate the associated 95% confidence intervals.

In your data, there is only one y value for each x value, so there is no way to calculate a confidence interval.